# google-files-api

Tags: file-upload, system, backend

I'm looking for a web-based system to simply manage libraries as private packages.

Comment: As in you'd like a pre-written system you can deploy rather than help writing one yourself?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point here, but couldn't you just throw up an FTP server?

Comment: I want to serve hundreds of zipped micro-api's and asset packages by http. I need a solution to manage this tangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a different perspective it seems you want to build an online repository of JavaScript libraries.  I've seen people making efforts to use [Maven for JavaScript library management](http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/) and you would "**manage the tangle**" with a repository manager (like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/)). I dare say there are other similar offerings if Maven isn't your thing (Gradle, Grapes, Ivy ...).

*(Moved from comments, as I thought this wasn't so much seeking clarification as it was suggesting a solution)*